how can I print a shared_ptr class?
How can I print a shared_ptr? I have to print sp1 and sp2 via void print(), but I have no clue how to do it.
This is the code:
struct MediaAsset
{
    virtual ~MediaAsset() = default; // make it polymorphic
};

struct Song : public MediaAsset
{
    std::string artist;
    std::string title;

    Song(const std::string& artist_, const std::string& title_) :
        artist{ artist_ }, title{ title_ }
    {
        std::cout << "Song " << artist_ << " - " << title_ << " constructed\n";
    }

    ~Song()
    {
        std::cout << "~Song " << artist << " - " << title << " destructed\n";
    }

    void print()
    {
        //Complete to show information about the current object
    }
};

using namespace std;

void example1()
{
    auto sp1 = make_shared<Song>("poets","carnival");
    shared_ptr<Song> sp2(new Song("poets","late goodbye") );
    sp1.print();
    sp2.print();
}

I wrote:
void print()
{
    std::cout << "artist " << artist << " - " << "title" << title << " end\n";
}

and this is the message I get when I run the program:

error: 'class std::shared_ptr<Song>' has no member named 'print'


Worth noting this isn't really a shared_ptr specific issue. If you had a raw pointer (or other smart pointer) you'd need to use -> instead of ..

Exactly the same way that you would do it with a regular pointer sp1->print(). Smart pointers are designed to operate as closely as possible to regular pointers.

The error message is correect. print() is not a method of shared_ptr itself. You need to dereference the shared_ptr to access the actual Song object, and then you can access its members as needed, eg:
auto sp1 = make_shared<Song>("poets","carnival");
shared_ptr<Song> sp2(new Song("poets","late goodbye") );
sp1->print();
sp2->print();

Or:
auto sp1 = make_shared<Song>("poets","carnival");
shared_ptr<Song> sp2(new Song("poets","late goodbye") );
(*sp1).print();
(*sp2).print();

